# Split a dataframe into two files based on the values of a column

Tags: python, sklearn-pandas

I need to split a dataframe into 2 parts. For example if the below dataframe is split randomly based on Col1 both the files should contain samples from each category 1,2 and 3.

```
Col1 col2 
1      a
1      b
2      c
2      d
3      e
```

So far I am able to split the data into desired ratio by using `sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split`. **But I am not able to figure out how should splitting be done to pick up samples from every category.**
All help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `StratifiedKFold` object.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.StratifiedKFold.html

There is a short example in the doc showing how to use it